# Selenium chrome webdriver, Python. Translate webpage content

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello i am using `selenium.webdriver.chrome` in Python and doing some web scraping. I would like to translate website content from english to polish right before obtaining page source. I am aware of the options you can set up:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=pl")
```

But it isnt what I need. In chrome you can right click anytime and select "translate to ..." option. I am wondering is there any way to translate the content of the page in order to get scraped data already translated for you. Is it possible? And if so how could you do it?

To answear the question about where is the scraped data residing:
I am not sure if thats what you mean but basically when i am at the right page i am running this piece of code:

```
html_doc = driver.page_source
bs = soup(html_doc, 'html5lib')
tag = bs.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'location-meta-block'})
print(tag[1].text)
```

This is my output:
`POLIN Muzeum Historii Zydow Polskich4,146 reviewsul. Mordechaja Anielewicza 6, Warsaw, Mazovia Province, Central Poland, Polandul. Mordechaja Anielewicza 6, Warsaw`

I would like to translate the webpage content before running
html_doc = driver.page_source

Comment: where is the _scraped data_ residing?

Comment: i have edited my post and tried to answear your question

Comment: When you right-click in Google Chrome and select the option to translate a page, Chrome uses Google Translate to do so behind the scenes. I would suggest that you see if you can use [Google Translate webpage](https://translate.google.com/) with the URL of the page you want to translate to reach your goal. But I don't know if you could use it for a lot of pages in a short time.